# Convert 2D Double to 2D Float

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, casting, floating-point

Does anybody know how to convert a two dimensional array from double to float I have the following:

```
double [][] matrix = new double[width][height];
```

I want to convert the data within the variable data to Flaot so i have a new variable as follows:

```
float [][] floatmatrix = new float[width][height];
```

I tried casting but its not allowed e.g

```
float[][] data = (float[][]) result;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to copy it entry by entry (in two nested loops):

```
    float[][] floatmatrix = new float[width][height];
    for (w = 0; width > w; w++) {
        for (h = 0; height > h; h++) {
            floatmatrix[w][h] = (float) matrix[w][h];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A more self-contained function:

> Input Shape will be automatically inferred.
> You can use it to convert any type to any type. Just convert `double` to your source data type, and `float` to target data type.

```
public float[][] d2fConverter(double[][] _tfIdf){
    float[][] tfIdf = new double[_tfIdf.length][_tfIdf[0].length];
    for (int w = 0; _tfIdf.length > w; w++) {
        for (int h = 0; _tfIdf[0].length > h; h++) {
            tfIdf[w][h] = (float) _tfIdf[w][h];
        }
    }
    return tfIdf;
}
```